# Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, pymysql

```
def write_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)

class DownloadPhoto(Resource):
    def get(self,PhotoDefaultID):
        connection_DownloadPhoto = pymysql.connect(host='123',
        user='123',
        password='123',
        db='123',
        charset='123',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        with connection_DownloadPhoto.cursor() as cursor_DownloadPhoto:
            DownloadPhoto = "SELECT `PhotoData` FROM `app_phototable` WHERE `PhotoDefaultID` IN (%s)"
            cursor_DownloadPhoto.execute(DownloadPhoto, PhotoDefaultID)
            PhotoData = cursor_DownloadPhoto.fetchone()
            connection_DownloadPhoto.commit()
    finally:
        connection_DownloadPhoto.close()
    write_file(PhotoData['PhotoData'], "Photo.jpg")
    return send_file("Photo.jpg", mimetype = "image/jpg"), 200
```

I`m trying to set a image server using Pymysql Flask restful and it says that 
    TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable // Werkzeug Debugger

Anybody Can Help？

Comment: Please give us the actual exception, with traceback, not a description of it that doesn't tell us where the error happened.

Comment: As a side note, do you actually need the files saved on the filesystem? If not, you may want to stream it directly from memory (although you should test both ways—sometimes the performance benefit of `X-Sendfile` is worth the cost of saving a tempfile…).

Comment: A few more things: (1) Is this your actual indentation? If not, please fix it. If so, your `get` method doesn't really do anything useful. (2) What is the `commit()` for? You don't seem to be doing any updates, only a select. (3) Do you really want to open a new database connection for every request instead of caching them? (I think Flask has ways of making that easy…) If so, why not use another `with` statement?

Comment: The exception doesn`t really tell much but I`m pretty sure errors are at the last line. Or how can I stream it from memory??

Comment: Get method is used to get a specific image from database, doing GET and not POST

Comment: Where does that `Resource` type come from? Is this `Flask-RESTful`? If so, when you `return val, status` from a `get` method, by default it assumes you're returning JSON, and it won't handle anything else without custom code. See [here](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#content-negotiation) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you're using Flask-RESTful, and that your `Resource` object is supposed to be a REST resource, as defined by that library.

If so, [as explained in the docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#content-negotiation):

> Out of the box, Flask-RESTful is only configured to support JSON. We made this decision to give API maintainers full control of over API format support; so a year down the road you don’t have to support people using the CSV representation of your API you didn’t even know existed. To add additional mediatypes to your API, you’ll need to declare your supported representations on the **Api** object.

Presumably this is the part you're missing.

When you call `send_file`, that returns a `flask.Response` object that knows how to do an `X-Sendfile` if configured properly or send binary data if not. Either way, that's not something you can, or want to, encode with JSON.

See [Response Formats](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#response-formats) for examples of configuring Flask-RESTFUL to handle other kinds of responses besides JSON, but I think it'll be as simple as this:

```
@api.representation('image/jpeg')
def output_response(resp, code, headers):
    # This function expects an already-created flask.Response object,
    # which is a little unusual, but since that's the way you're trying
    # to use it, let's take advantage of that (and hope it works; I've
    # never tried it...)
    resp.headers.extend(headers or {})
    return resp
```

Comment: I think thats the problem Thanks